# Biblatex : date range inherited from parent with crossref

Tags: biblatex, date

In the following example, the `@article` inherits its `date` from the `@mvbook`, but doesn't display the range correctly (cf. screenshot). If I remove `{date=1983}` from the `@article` in my .bib file, the problem disappears.

[1) But I'd prefer not to edit all these entries manually : what could I do to display the date range (actually a year range) correctly ?]

2) Ideally, though, I'd prefer to keep the date from the child, i.e. `@article`, and disregard the date range in the parent, i.e. `@mvbook`. I thought it was the default behaviour. Indeed, the Biblatex documentation (§ 4.5.11) says explicitly that child fields are not overridden by parent fields by default…

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@mvbook{mvbook,
  location = {London},
  title = {Multivolume},
  volumes = {2},
  author = {Jane Doe},
  date = {1982/1983}
}

@incollection{article1,
  location = {London},
  title = {Article},
  volume = {2},
  booktitle = {Multivolume},
  author = {Jane Doe},
  date = {1983},
  pages = {675--779},
  crossref = {mvbook}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref} % hyperliens PDF
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum\footcite{mvbook} dolor sit amet\footcite{article1}…


\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

Citations:
[image: Citation]

Bibliography:
[image: Bibliography]

Comment: Mhhh, yes by default the `year` and `endyear` fields are inherited by the `@incollection`. Existing fields are not overwritten, however, so you end up with `year = 1983` and `endyear = 1983`. You probably want to block inheritance of `end...` dates if `...` already exists. I found that the same happens if you include a month or day in the date of the `mvbook`. I can't see a way to prevent inheritance conditionally on a year being in `@incollection`, maybe you need to start [a feature request on github](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues) if no answer comes up here in due time.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more explicit about the core of the problem above. Internally the `date` field is decomposed into the parts (amongst others) `year` and `endyear` and for inheritance these are considered separately. The parent has both a `year` and `endyear` while the child has only a `year`. The child's year is not overwritten (existing fields are not overwritten), but it gets the new `endyear`. You can note the same effect with month and day if you have `date = {1982-06-01},` in `mvbook` and `date = {1983},` in `article1`. You will end up with "1 January 1983" for the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Then, I understand that the child has `year = {1983}` which has not been overwritten, and `endyear = {1983}` which it has inherited from its parent. Biblatex spots the inconsistency of this pseudo date range 1983-1983 and dismisses the `year`. It keeps the `endyear` and its hyphen (-1983) and I'm keen on considering this hyphen as a welcome warning. I think that it could be decided that Biblatex blocks inheritance of a date range when there's already a date in the child. That would be my feature request (I'll open it on github later, waiting for comments here first)

Comment: For bookkeeping purposes, the issue has been raised at the `biblatex` bugtracker [#439](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/439) and has already been addressed by the developers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a bug in `biblatex` that has been resolved in `biblatex` 3.5. With that version of `biblatex` the MWE looks just fine.